# Can I get ETH in redistribution wallet

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, ethereumjs

I am trying to create a token on Ethereum, basic one like usual redistribution tokens that sends a percentage to my wallet on sells.
I am receiving tokens in the wallet, but I want to use that wallet as buyback wallet.
Is it possible to get ether to my wallet instead of tokens. Like when a seller sells, he sells and the ether gets transferred to my wallet, not my tokens.

Is there any token doing that?
I am trying to make it unique.

Let me know,
regards :)

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure thats not possible unless you create your own DEX and build this function into it